# Flutter drop down button issue

Tags: flutter

I'm currently working with a flutter project...i'need a solution about how to create a simple questionnaires and answer in the drop down button with having some score to calculate final score for your answers

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem are you having with DropDownButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to build a quiz app. 
please reference this doc Flutter: how to build a quiz game
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-how-to-build-a-quiz-game-596d0f369575

and github code is here https://github.com/frideosapps/trivia_example 
You can fork this directly.

demo of this app

[image]